# MySql insert the results of a select

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I would like to know if I can run a request like that:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (a, b) 
VALUES (
 SELECT a, b
 FROM `t1` AS o
 WHERE o.id NOT 
 IN (
  SELECT a
  FROM t2 
  )
)
```

The idea is to fill the t2 with some data from the t1, but I must be wrong on the syntax.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You don't use the `VALUES` keyword when inserting from a `SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO t2 (a, b) 
 SELECT a, b
 FROM `t1` AS o
 WHERE o.id NOT 
 IN (
  SELECT a
  FROM t2 
  )
```

Answer (score 6):

remove the `values`

like

```
INSERT INTO t2 (a, b) 
SELECT a, b
FROM `t1` AS o
WHERE o.id NOT 
IN 
(
  SELECT a
  FROM t2 
);
```

OR a more readble format

```
INSERT INTO t2 (a, b) 
SELECT o.a, o.b
FROM `t1` AS o
LEFT JOIN t2 ON o.id=t2.a
WHERE t2.a IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

You dont need the VALUES in your query.

Comment: this what we call a smart answer!