# How to insert a value using mysql query in DB for all the rows except few

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a DB table structure with around 6000 rows as given below:.

```
carrier|make|model
```

My need is to create an sql Query such that I can insert a Make-Model pair for all the carriers except few(say ATT, bell-mobility, virgin Canada and Warranty ATT).

How can I get this done?

Comment: insert to a new table ?

Comment: insert needs to be in same table for which structure is given

Comment: what's your data source??

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty My bad.. I re-corrected myself

Comment: You mean you want to prevent inserting certain values?

Comment: Are you adding new rows, or updating existing rows?

Comment: @Goon10 I am supposed to execute the query directly into the Database, hence the data/value to be inserted is manual

Comment: @fancyPants I am preventing insert on certain values of carrier

Comment: This doesn't make sense; per your comment, your table is currently empty; then how will you determine the carrier field values?

Comment: @Rahul He says the table has 6000 rows. That's not empty.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes but it's still confusing !!!

Comment: @Rahul: No. It is clear now. OP wants to copy rows with carriers and same make and model into new rows but limited to specific carriers. Title should be changed. *Copy some rows where carrier not in.*

Comment: @Rahul, Barmar has striked the right chord..... please follow Barmar's Understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (carrier, make, model)
SELECT DISTINCT carrier, "Samsung", "Galaxy S5"
FROM table_name
WHERE carrier NOT IN ( 'ATT', 'bell-mobility', 'virgin Canada', 'Warranty ATT' )
```

To add multiple new makes and models you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (carrier, make, model)
SELECT a.carrier, b.make, b.model
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT carrier
      FROM table_name
      WHERE carrier NOT IN ( 'ATT', 'bell-mobility', 'virgin Canada', 'Warranty ATT' ) AS a
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT "Samsung" AS make, "Galaxy 5" AS model
     UNION
     SELECT "Nokia" AS make, "Lumia" AS model
     ...
    ) AS b
```

BTW, this question suggests that you have a poor database design. You should have a table of carriers that lists all the carriers you know of, you shouldn't get it from the table that lists the makes and models for each carrier. This is an example of poor normalization, because if you ever stop supplying phones for some carrier, you'll totally forget that they exist.

Comment: M I right for "SELECT DISTINCT carrier, :new_make, :new_model"

SELECT DISTINCT carrier, :Samsung, :Galaxy S5

Comment: @Rahul My understanding is that the table currently has 6,000 rows in it. He's trying to add new makes and models for all of the carriers that are already in the table, except for the 4 in the list.

Comment: @Rahul: No update is not correct. I too thought OP was expecting an update and I answered for it. But I removed my answer.

Comment: Yeah, there'll be redundancy,I take it there's no primary key constraint.

Comment: @Barmar, what I dont want to filer the query for those 4 carriers?, What If I just want the insert query for all the available carriers in table?

Comment: Then take out the `WHERE` clause and it will use all carriers.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL iNSERT SYNTAX - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

If you're talking about PHP, take a look at this page: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

**EDIT:**

A good solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472948/1564840).

And if you use the above solution, the result should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO table ("carrier", "make", "model") 
 SELECT DISTINCT carrier, make, model
 FROM `table2` AS o
 WHERE o.name NOT 
 IN ( "ATT", "bell-mobility", "virgin Canada", "Warranty ATT"  )
```

Comment: I downvoted because this is a useless answer. It doesn't have anything specific to the user's question, it's just generic information about syntax.

Comment: you edited your answer, first you suggested an update, I haven't downvoted your answer..not everyone is such a "I NEED VOTES" like you..

Comment: I posted this answer because, as you can see, the user who asked this question don't know how to use Mysql Insert, that's why it's so generic

Comment: Thanks Pascut.... Though You need to edit little correction as your query will insert for duplicate values as well if duplicate rows already poresend for carrier