# Select query inside a insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a insert query which contains a select query. The problem is that it does not seem to work, but they work separately.

The select query select the highest number from the numbers table and then it need to add 1 to it. the $variables is from php.

What am i doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO numbers (number, storeID, udid)
VALUES (
    (SELECT number
     FROM numbers
     WHERE storeid = '$var' AND DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE() 
     ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
    ) + 1, $var, $udid)
```

Comment: Show more code. The PHP variables don't interpolate.

Comment: Hey, show more code! Are you running this in a MySQL console? I doubt. So show the surroundings of the code ->> the PHP

Comment: Duplicate of [MySql insert the results of a select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472929/mysql-insert-the-results-of-a-select).  Also, your query looks like it could be vulnerable to SQL Injection, you should be using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a variable storing the incremented value first

```
$results = mysqli_query($con, "Select number FROM numbers where storeid= '$var' AND DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE() Order by number DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
  extract($row);
  $incremented_value = $row['number'] + 1;
}
```

Then, the number of columns must be identical

```
INSERT INTO numbers (number, storeID, udid) 
VALUES 
($incremented_value, $var, $udid)
```